# HBase: How to skip row with specific column in hbase?

Tags: filter, hbase

is there any filter can be used to skip rows that contains specific column ?
eg

```
      name price invalid
r1       a    10
r2       b     5       1
r3       c    20
```

i just want row without invalid column (r1, r3)

i tried `SingleColumnValueFilter` but it always skip row when the column is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.. Use the same SingleColumnValue filter and and compare with a value that can never be set to that column, like if you are planning to store integer have a comparision with charecter!

SingleColumnValueFilter('ColumnFamily','Qualifier',!=,'binary:x',false,true)

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: thanks for answer, but it seems not work for me..the column value is variable, i can not use NOT_EQUAL to skip them

Comment: I just edited the answer, I dont know if you got notified about it or not now I have filterIfColumnMissing_boolean = false, so if that column doesnt exist it will get the row any way, and if it does it will compare it with some value(which will never be set to this column) and not return those rows with that column in it.

Comment: thanks very much, i try "invalid", EQUAL, "&(@*#&^@*&%", it works now !